# Autolayout programmatically to UISearchController disappear when select it

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` and I have added an `UISearchController` programmatically:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var searchBarPlaceholder: UIView!
 -------------------------------------------------
 ...
 searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
 searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    
 searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
 searchBarPlaceholder.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
 automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
 definesPresentationContext = true
    
 searchController.delegate = self
 searchController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
 let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchController.searchBar, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: searchBarPlaceholder, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) // add margin
    
 let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchController.searchBar, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: searchBarPlaceholder, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    
 let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchController.searchBar, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: searchBarPlaceholder, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
   
 self.searchBarPlaceholder.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint])
```

And when I click to search on the search bar, it totally disappear:

[image: SearchBar disappear]

And when I'm rotate the device I get this error:

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc499782ee0 h=-&- v=--& _UISearchBarContainerView:0x7fc49b9cb3f0.width == _UISearchControllerView:0x7fc4997603b0.width - 667>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc4997655c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[_UISearchControllerView:0x7fc4997603b0(375)]>"
```

Also I added a `UISearchControllerDelegate` method but it doesn't work:

```
 func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.superview == nil {
        for searchCtrlChildView in searchController.view.subviews {
            if searchCtrlChildView.frame.origin == CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) {
                searchCtrlChildView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I remove the `NSLayoutConstraint`s it works perfectly but I really need the `NSLayoutConstraint`s because I need to work in both orientations.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Cross check the UIView constraints and also haven't you missed height constraint or will it defined automatically.

Comment: The UIView has height constraint

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchController` will remove searchBar from current superview and add to `_UISearchBarContainerView` when it is actived. So autolayout will be failed.

This workaround below works for me, using ReactiveCocoa(for hook) & Masonry(for setConstraint)

```
@weakify(self);
[[[self.searchController.searchBar
 rac_signalForSelector:@selector(didMoveToSuperview)]
filter:^BOOL(id value) {
    @strongify(self);
    return self.searchController.searchBar.superview != nil;
}]
subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    @strongify(self);
    //fix wrong layout when controller is actived
    UISearchBar *searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
    [searchBar mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.and.trailing.and.top.equalTo(searchBar.superview);
        if (searchBar.superview != self.view) {
            //use low level priority to ensure works on future
            make.top.and.bottom.equalTo(searchBar.superview).priority(UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel-1);
        }
    }];
    //fix wrong layout when navigationBar.translucent=NO
    if (searchBar.superview != self.view) {
        UIView *view = searchBar.superview;
        [view mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.leading.and.trailing.and.top.equalTo(view.superview).priority(UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel-1);
        }];
    }
}];
```

And make sure `self.definesPresentationContext` set to `YES`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps into your storyboard

1. remove all constraints to your search bar and in your view controller also code also for frame or constrain code.
2. place your search bar into your view controller, and select your search bar and drag left side by clicking right click on your mouse and select leading space to your view
3. Do drag right side by clicking right click on your mouse and select Trailing space to your view
4. Drag top and bottom and select top and bottom options to your view.

// see the difference then you can able to do easily

Comment: I know how to add a `UISearchBar` with Autolayout on the storyboard. I need to use a `UISearchController` not a `UISearchBar` thats the reason I'm doing this programmatically.

Comment: Garbage comment